# Not able to generate a pass file using signpass tool in iOS 7 and above

Tags: ios, passbook

I created a pkpass file and signed it using sign pass tool. The pass generated is opening fine in osx and ios6 but when i try to open it in iOS 7 and later , its not working. Please can i get a help of understanding as of where i am going wrong.

Comment: Attach your phone to Xcode when you try to add the pass to Passbook.  The console log will tell you why it is failing to add.  If you can post a link to your pass, then I can check for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , But i am trying to send the pkpass generated to the device through the mail, i am not even able to download the pass too.

Comment: Then watching the console of the device in Xcode as you try to install the pass is your only option to debug what is failing.  Post your console logs in your question if the cause is still not obvious.

Comment: when i try to open the attachment in the device mail client, i get it as null, it says there is no pkpass file in it . while it works for iOS 6

Comment: But what does the device console in Xcode say when you try to open the attachment?

Comment: i did not receive any logs

Comment: Sorry, but without either the pass or the logs, there's really not much we can do to help.